# c++ pcl_ros: How to generate point cloud with latest 100 messages

Tags: c++, ros, point-clouds, erase

I have a rostopic that receives a single frame (2D) point cloud (with x,y coordinates) per message and I need to create a (3D) point cloud concatenating the **latest 100** frames (over z axis). The purpose is to always show a point cloud made out of the **latest** 100 frames like a FIFO queue.

I can concatenate the frames using [cloud->points.push_back (pcl::PointXYZ(pt.x, pt.y, z));](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#a311d7f02461d7bd60df285251a74bcf3) method over the z axis.

The tricky part is after reaching up to 100 frames how to remove the oldest frame? (Ex: Remove points with z index 1) I was trying to use the method [points.erase (iterator first, iterator last)](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#a3e33f355a5913972b575e04831543d20) but, I don't know how to pass the **iterator** parameter. Even, if I could achieve that; how can I shift the existing point cloud to start from z=1? Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `cloud->points` is an std::vector, see [std::vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) for an example on how to pass the iterator parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I think I can use it to erase the first frame points. However regarding my next issue is how to shift the existing point cloud back by 1 from z index? Any idea how to modify the z index points of the existing cloud?  Is there an easy way to do this or should I have to iterate through each point and modify the z index? If so what is the method I should call to modify point z index? 
Can I use?
`cloud->points.z = cloud->points.z - 1;`

Comment: Take a look at [pcl::transformPointCloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.0/group__registration.html#gab353a6a8507fb4e788d6c3969acb82cf) to see if you can use this to translate your cloud without having to iterate through.